# How to browse a .zip file in IntelliJ (or .jar, etc.)

Tags: intellij-idea, zip

I'd like to be able to "open up" (without unzipping) .zip files or .jar files in IntelliJ much like you can do in Eclipse by clicking the twisty. How do I do this with IntelliJ?

Comment: Are they in your project? It should be browsable in the project view... for JARs at least. For dependencies on the classpath, you can find them under a Libraries sub-tree, I think...

Comment: They are in my project. I find it odd, in one folder it allows me to open one of the jars, but all the rest of the files in that folder are .jar files with no option to expand them.

Comment: @BhargavRao Why did you close this as off-topic? IntelliJ is definitely a tool primarily used for programming, making this question definitely on-topic.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel,  I saw a lot of the link only answers recommending plugins and more general computing IDE related stuff, so I closed it. Reopened it anyway.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Jar files visible in your project structure that cannot be expanded have not yet been "added" as libraries. Right click the jar file and select `Add as Library...`

Also see [Configuring Module Dependencies and Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

And: [Correct way to add lib/*.jar to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: That certainly helped, some .jar files I wanted to open are now available. However, the .war file that I have which is a collection of .jar files from my Ivy build, I'd like to be able to see is built correctly, but none of the "Add as Library.." options seem to make it "openable".

Comment: this does not answer the question - not add a dependency but browse (example -> open and examine content) :)

Comment: from where I stand, pme's answer pointing to the plugin archive browser should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 31):

There is now a **Intellij Plugin** that solves that:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9491-archive-browser

Update: it works now also for **nested archives**. (tested 2019.1)

Comment: I have installed but can't see figure out how to use it.

Comment: is it listed as installed as installed plugin in Intellij (restart is required)? Then any zip can be extended - I just tested that with the newest version of Intellij 2018.1

Comment: cool beans, that archive browser, works for me like a charm.
This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support jar, war, etc. Ironic because IntelliJ is Java focused.

Answer (score 5):

While [Christopher Peisert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10714424/4430939) works for archives that aren't nested (you are out of luck if you have an EAR containing WARs) it is tedious that for most archive types (JARs being the exception), you have to add the file as a library or a dependency from the **Project Structure** area of **Settings**.

If you want to see archives be the default operation and work for nested archives, please vote for this [YouTrack Issue 126376](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126376)

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Intellij plugin to implement it. It support basic archives and tar.gz extension, the key feature is nested archive support. It had uploaded to [Jetbrain repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11940-file-expander). You can install it from plugin marketplace. See plugin github page for more information 
[File Expander](https://github.com/Camork/file-expander-plugin).