# View xml.gz file Directly From Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am seeking for a plugin that can view the`.xml.gz` file directly from Intellij.

I tried to use the plugin called archive browser mentioned in this issue: [How to browse a .zip file in IntelliJ (or .jar, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712921/how-to-browse-a-zip-file-in-intellij-or-jar-etc)

However, I don't know if it is because my setting is not correct or any other mistakes, I can browse `.csv.gz` file after installing this extension (as the image below), however, for file with  `xml.gz`, it can still not be recognised.

Thanks very much for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding `*.gz` to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types | Archive`

Comment: Hi @EgorKlepikov, I tried your suggestions but got the notification saying "this wildcard is already registered by '7zip archive' filetype". I am wondering should I choose to reassign wildcard for this? Thanks

Comment: Try to temporarily remove this association from `7zip archive` file type.